# Bind to TextChanged event for TextBox in F# WPF MVVM application

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, f#, fsxaml

I'd like to bind to a WPF TextBox in an MVVM F# application built using FsXaml and FSharp.ViewModule. I added a command called "SetA" to the application described [here](http://marisks.net/2015/05/11/f-sharp-xaml-event-driven-mvvm/), and attempted to bind to it with the following XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Score.ScoreA, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="Lucida Console">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <fsx:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SetA}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

The TextBox is correctly populated from the ScoreA property, but the SetA command is not called when I type a new value in the TextBox. I'm comfortable with F#, but this is my first WPF MVVM application, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I trigger my SetA handler when the user changes the text value?

This is my ViewModel:

```
type MainViewModel(controller : Score -> ScoringEvent -> Score) as self = 
    inherit EventViewModelBase<ScoringEvent>()

    let score = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.Score @>, Score.zero)

    let eventHandler ev =
        score.Value <- controller score.Value ev

    do
        self.EventStream
        |> Observable.add eventHandler

    member this.IncA = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(IncA)
    member this.DecA = this.Factory.EventValueCommandChecked(DecA, (fun _ -> this.Score.ScoreA > 0), [ <@@ this.Score @@> ])
    member this.IncB = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(IncB)
    member this.DecB = this.Factory.EventValueCommandChecked(DecB, (fun _ -> this.Score.ScoreB > 0), [ <@@ this.Score @@> ])
    member this.NewGame = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(New)
    member this.SetA = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(SetA)

    member __.Score = score.Value
```

I only added the one line that defines SetA.

Comment: Show how your viewmodel is defined.

Comment: I updated the question to show the ViewModel.

Comment: It occurs to me that maybe I need to add a CommandParameter in order to tell the Command about the new value in the TextBox?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely the `Command` is being called, but the result is not what you'd expected.

For testing purposes try

```
member this.SetA = 
   this.Factory.CommandSync(
        fun _ -> System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("TextChanged","RoutedEv") |> ignore)
```

Note the `CommandSync` instead of `EventValueCommand`. No matter how you change the score, a msgbox will pop up.

You could also keep the `EventValueCommand`

```
member this.SetA = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(SetA)
```

and do the same in the `update` fun

```
let update score event =
    match event with
    | IncA -> {score with ScoreA = score.ScoreA + 1}
    | DecA -> {score with ScoreA = max (score.ScoreA - 1) 0}
    | IncB -> {score with ScoreB = score.ScoreB + 1}
    | DecB -> {score with ScoreB = max (score.ScoreB - 1) 0}
    | New -> zero 
    | SetA -> System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("TextChanged","RoutedEv") |> ignore ; score
```

Getting back to the *not what you'd expected* part, I assume you want the score in the scoreboard to update, when you change the `TextBox.Text` value.

As you've noticed there's no (pure) way to bring the `TextBox.Text` value into the `update` fun using the current `controller`.
Due to the fact that the SetX behaviour isn't fix, unlike in the case of the IncX, DecX or New events.

Options:

- You could change the signature of the controller to `Score -> ScoringEvent -> string option -> Score` and use the option value to handle SetX events in the `update` fun.
- You could handle everything in the `ViewModel`. 
  The immutable nature of the record forces the use of a `OneWay Binding`. I would keep it immutable, but you can (de)compose everything in the ViewModel.

Try

**ViewModel**

```
type MainViewModel(controller : Score -> ScoringEvent -> Score) as self = 
    inherit EventViewModelBase<ScoringEvent>()

    let scoreA = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.ScoreA @>, 0)
    let scoreB = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.ScoreB @>, 0)

    let updateVM score = 
        scoreA.Value <- score.ScoreA
        scoreB.Value <- score.ScoreB

    let eventHandler ev = 
        updateVM <| controller {ScoreA = scoreA.Value ; ScoreB = scoreB.Value} ev

    do
        self.EventStream
        |> Observable.add eventHandler

    member this.IncA = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(IncA)
    member this.DecA = this.Factory.EventValueCommandChecked(DecA, (fun _ -> this.ScoreA > 0), [ <@@ this.ScoreA @@> ])
    member this.IncB = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(IncB)
    member this.DecB = this.Factory.EventValueCommandChecked(DecB, (fun _ -> this.ScoreB > 0), [ <@@ this.ScoreB @@> ])
    member this.NewGame = this.Factory.EventValueCommand(New)

    member __.ScoreA
        with get() = scoreA.Value 
         and set v = scoreA.Value <- v
    member __.ScoreB
        with get() = scoreB.Value 
         and set v = scoreB.Value <- v
```

**XAML**

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="75" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF3A3A3A">
        <Button Height="70" Width="70" Margin="2" Command="{Binding NewGame}">
            <TextBlock Text="New" FontSize="18"></TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ScoreA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Margin="2" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="#FF024D70" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid>
                <Viewbox>
                    <Label Content="{Binding ScoreA}" ContentStringFormat="D2" FontFamily="Lucida Console"></Label>
                </Viewbox>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Command="{Binding DecA}"  Height="70" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5" Margin="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="-" FontSize="36" Height="60"></TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding IncA}"  Height="70" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5" Margin="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="+" FontSize="36" Height="60"></TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FF7E0E03" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid>
                <Viewbox>
                    <Label Content="{Binding ScoreB}" ContentStringFormat="D2"  FontFamily="Lucida Console"></Label>
                </Viewbox>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Command="{Binding DecB}"  Height="70" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5" Margin="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="-" FontSize="36" Height="60"></TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding IncB}"  Height="70" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5" Margin="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="+" FontSize="36" Height="60"></TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

*Notes*

- `Score.ScoreX` changed to `ScoreX`
- `Text="{Binding Score.ScoreA, Mode=OneWay}"` changed to `Text="{Binding ScoreA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`
- Removed the `Interaction.Trigger`

Comment: You're right. My command was being called with a TextChangedEventArgs, when I expected a string. I guess I need to user a converter. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @brianberns It's fairly easy to write the converters using FS.VM - there are base classes specifically to allow you to extract that.  I believe the FsXaml drawing application has some examples (using MouseEventArgs -> custom types)